# what is best way to design neo4j graph when relation also have some information to be node

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

Suppose we have person entity and trip relation to destination entity like city , and we wanna add 3 or 4 kind of information like transportation( type , ticket number , date , .. ) ,that must be node as itself to this relation ..

The question is how we can graph this?

Comment: Unfortunately, Relationships can not have information(i.e. Property) that would be a node type. You should consider creating nodes instead of relationships for Trips. Another way is to store the id of the transportation node as a trip property but it's not recommended.

Comment: You seem to be saying that you "must" attach a third node (that has the `transportation` label) to an existing `trip` relationship. Since relationships must have exactly two endpoints, that is not possible. Can you explain why you think that "must" be done, and why you cannot just put the transportation properties in the `trip` relationship?

Comment: @cybersam
i`m not tell that must be done , i wanna know if you have information on more than one node and you want to make relation from start to one of them , how it is possible  to involve anothers node also .
real word example : you are going to another county , this nodes may be involve 
person , passport , visa , plain , airline , ticket , boarder , date , those are things that have property also , so how can graph the trip to destination with all of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to have more than 2 nodes connected to a single relationship.

However, as a workaround, you can "reify" a relationship type as a node label, and create extra relationship types to connect to that new label.

For example, if your current data model is as follows:

```
(p:Person)-[:TRIP_TO]->(c:City), (transp:Transporation)
```

and you want to also associate each `TRIP_TO` relationship with a `Transportation` node, you can reify the `TRIP_TO` relationship by replacing `-[:TRIP_TO]->` with  `-[:TAKES]->(trip:Trip)-[:TO]->`, like so:

```
(p)-[:TAKES]->(trip:Trip)-[:TO]->(c)
```

and adding another new relationship type to connect the `Trip` node to the appropriate `Transportation` node:

```
(trip)-[:USES]->(transp)
```

Comment: you mean use middle node and from that node i make relation to any node i want ? like sql ? let me check , tanks anyway

Comment: Yes, once the relationship is turned into a node, it can have any number of relationships to other nodes.